# explain how does Rectenna work to someone with some college level physics

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, antennas

I understand that [rectifying antenna](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectenna) (rectenna) is supposed to convert electromagnetic energy to electric current however I do not understand how it's really working.

I do get that it's kind of like how transformer works, but beyond that I am clueless. Could someone explain this to me?

Comment: What's Rectenna?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectenna

Comment: I think the wiki article and its links is sufficient to answer your question

Comment: but it wasn't that's why i posted the link as well.....

Comment: Is it that the reason for converting RF energy to DC is not really clear to you? (after all, they are both forms of energy). If so, I think I can answer.

Comment: what i dont understand is how Electromagnetic waves (radio) convert to electricity.